# Android Studio fetching an old artifact

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio to download an artifact that's available within an internal maven repository. At times Android Studio fails to fetch the latest Snapshot which results in compilation errors. Is there any workaround for this problem ?

Comment: Can you paste your build file here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Gradle forums at http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_get_gradle_to_download_newer_snapshots_to_gradle_cache_when_using_an_ivy_repository:

> Since SNAPSHOTs are a Maven concept, they aren't treated as anything special in an 'ivy' repository. Unfortunately, there's not (yet) any way to specify a custom pattern for a 'maven' repository, so you're a bit stuck.
>
> The best way to tell Gradle to check for updated versions of a dependency is to flag the dependency as 'changing'. Gradle will then check for updates every 24 hours, but this can be configured using the resolutionStrategy DSL.

```
configurations.all {
    // check for updates every build
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
dependencies {
    compile group: "group", name: "projectA", version: "1.1-SNAPSHOT", changing: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make Android Studio refresh its artifacts by using the command **Invalidate Caches / Restart**, which is in the **File** menu. I first used this command on Android Studio 3.2.1. It may exist on older versions too.

I use this after loading a new version of an external library (an AAR file) as a module, if classes or methods have been added or changed.